# Does the Windows API (not CRT) have a memory compare function?

Tags: windows, winapi, memory

I know I can use memcmp in Windows but I'm wondering if there's something native to the platform like CompareMemory. I have heard of RtlCompareMemory but that's for drivers apparently.

Comment: The CRT implementation of `memcmp` that comes with Visual Studio calls `RtlCompareMemory` (for 64bit systems anyway).

Comment: RtlCompareMemory seems not to be offical. It seems that not all Windows versions had this function (it seems to be missing in Windows 9x/ME) so it may be removed in future versions of Windows, too. There is no reason for Microsoft to add a second memory comparison function when msvcrt.dll already contains one.

Comment: @Martin You've got things backwards. It's not the OS that is implemented in terms of the CRT but rather the other way around. There is nothing unofficial about [`RtlCompareMemory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff561778.aspx) either. Removing this function from Windows will render a significant amount of drivers useless as well. This is not going to happen.

Comment: @IInspectable: Yes, it is official - but only for kernel-mode drivers. For Windows XP it works for applications, too, but it is not said that this is true for future versions of Windows. What I wanted to say about memcmp() is that this function is officially delivered with Windows (in msvcrt.dll) so you can rely on the fact that the function is there. Therefore there is no reason for anoter function doing the same job.

Comment: @Martin `<memory.h>` is not part of the Windows SDK. Neither is msvcrt.dll nor does it officially ship with Windows. There is only one function to compare blocks of memory as far as Windows is concerned, `RtlCompareMemory`. It **can** be used from kernel mode, but there is no restriction that it **must** only be used from kernel mode.

Answer (score 1):

According to this
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/99456/win32-equivalents-for-c-run-time-functions

It would appear there is no Win32 equivalent to memcmp.

It is also worth noting that RtlCompareMemory's return value is different from memcmp. It returns the count of identical bytes.

Answer (score 0):

There is the "RtlEqualMemory" macro in the Windows API. It returns TRUE if the Destination and Source are same, and FALSE otherwise.

```
#define RtlEqualMemory(Destination,Source,Length) (!memcmp((Destination),(Source),(Length)))
```